# What is the effect of dust particles on air pressure?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, air

Is there any change of atmospheric air pressure if dust particles are present (which really does)?

Answer (score 2):

A few micron scale dust particle has trillions of atoms in it and is around 100 mean-free paths in size, so it is macroscopic on the scale of molecular oxygen and nitrogen: it does not affect pressure.

Note that if you are trying to use a supersonic parachute on Mars, dust is a serious concern, as solar radiation heats the dust and the dust heats the atmosphere making it less dense, thereby reducing drag.